# Net Core Environments Not Switching

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am having trouble making my environments switch between development and staging.

It stays at staging no matter what the environment variable is.

Here is my launchsettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/WebService",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51658/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      }
    },
    "WebService": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51659/"
    }
  }
}
```

No matter what launch profile I use, the environment remains at 'Staging'

As far as appsettings.X.json go, I have 3.

```
appsettings.json
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.Staging.json
```

Comment: What OS are you using and how do you set your environment variable?

Comment: Windows 10 and through the profiles themselves. In the environmentVariables section

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the environment by setting the windows environment variables. The correct `appsettings.json` file will be loaded using this environment.

This can be done using the command line by executing

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

[This website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments#setting-the-environment) shows how to set the environment for different operating systems.

Comment: Really? What if I am hosting a staging and a production environment on the same server... Surely this can't be the right way?

Comment: you can create the environment variables based on users. as well.. IF you need to host both on the same server.

Comment: The documentation states that environment variables can be set for every session.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depend what you use for maintaining application Docker, IIS or something.

Docs says:

> Per IIS Application Pool
>
> To set environment variables for individual apps running in isolated
>   Application Pools (supported on IIS 10.0+), see the AppCmd.exe command
>   section of the Environment Variables  topic.

You probably need run applications on isolated environment and for that env you need set that variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Comment: Using IIS but not 10.0+